# Calculate the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over(n+3)(n+5)}$

Tags: integration

Calculate the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over(n+3)(n+5)}$$

I think that could use, $$\frac{1}{(n+3)(n+5)}=\frac{1}{2(n+3)}-\frac{1}{2(n+5)}$$

Comment: There are quite a few grammatical issues, and the upper bound of the sum cannot be $n$.

Comment: It's a telescoping series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: then,, what? \infty ?

Comment: @AndrewNew After you did your simplification, do **actually** sum up the first 4-5 expressions  and observe the pattern...

Comment: convention would be $\sum_\limits {i = 1}^n$

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n+3}-\dfrac{1}{n+5}=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n+3}-\dfrac{1}{n+4}\right)+\left(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n+4}-\dfrac{1}{n+5}\right)=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}$, so the rest should be easy.

Comment: What rest?  Didn't you, like, do everything here?

Comment: Don't forget the 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

Other way:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n+3}-\frac1{n+5}\\
&=\frac14+\frac15+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac1{n+3}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n+5}\\
&=\frac14+\frac15+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n+5}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n+5}\\
&=\frac14+\frac15
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

To make
user284331's answer rigorous:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{m}(\dfrac{1}{n+3}-\dfrac{1}{n+5})
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(\dfrac{1}{n+3}-\dfrac{1}{n+4})+\sum_{n=1}^{m}(\dfrac{1}{n+4}-\dfrac{1}{n+5})\\
&=\sum_{n=4}^{m+3}(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1})+\sum_{n=5}^{m+4}(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1})\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac1{m+4}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac1{m+4}\\
&\to\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}
\qquad\text{as } m \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: +1 because this way shows that you don't have to worry about reordering affecting the value of the series.